# highstock - Points doesn't match Y axis scale

Tags: javascript, highcharts

using Highstock JS v2.1.5, I'm facing a the following problem:

[image]

There are just two posible values (1 or 2), but when the serie has a lot of elements (picture example has 2000) I don't know why the chart (spline or line) draws some of them in the middle.

I tried a lot of configurations, but always does the same behavior. Could it be a issue of that version? Should I have to upgrade to another? There is any parameter that I didn't realize that does it or avoids it?

jsfiddle.net/MorettyBtt/ck3seLoy/33

Thanks!

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue on some online editor which I could work on? Without the code example, it's hard to say what could have an impact on it.

Comment: Take a look, please & thank you!!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/MorettyBtt/ck3seLoy/33/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, did you have look at the online editor? Is there any chance to fix it or do I have to get rid off highcharts/highstocks from our platform and use another opensource library? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for rendering those points is a `dataGrouping`. https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping

Demo with disabled dataGrouping options: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5731dkyq/

```
var series = ([{
    yAxis: 0,
    name: 'Parcatge ( )',
    lineWidth: 0,
    pointPlacement: 'on',
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        },
    marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 2
    },
    data: [...],
 }])
```